# jwplayer 6: get filename

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Is it possible to get the filename of the current jwplayer loaded file?

```
jwplayer('player_1').setup({
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  file: "http://domain.com/filename.mp4"
});
```

I came across this http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference#playlist but not sure if this will work in my case.

```
alert(jwplayer('player_1').getPlaylistItem().index);
```

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind. Figured it out:

```
var theFile;
if(jwplayer('player_1').config.levels){
  theFile = jwplayer('player_1').getPlaylistItem()['levels'][0]['file'];
} 
else {
  theFile = jwplayer('player_1').getPlaylistItem()['file'];
}

alert(theFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jwplayer('player_1').onPlaylistItem(function(event){

     index = jwplayer('player_1').getPlaylistIndex();
     item = jwplayer('player_1').getPlaylistItem(index);

     theFile = item.file;
     alert(theFile);
 });
```